Unable to create a java class in intellij ide
I am trying to create a java class in intellij id by right clicking on main folder then going to new option but inside new option it is showing html file js file typescript file package.json but not showing java class option why? How to make. A java class in intellij ide.
I am doing following
In main folder of my project right click->New-> here I should find java class but java class is not there.
Other types of file I am able to create here javascript file typescript file html file.

Did you create one Java Project? Any screenshot is welcome.

It seems like your project is not recognized as a Java project in IntelliJ IDEA.
To create a Java class in IntelliJ IDEA, you can try the following steps:

Right-click on the source folder (usually named 'src') in your project directory.
Select "New" -> "Java Class" from the context menu.
In the dialog that opens, enter the name of your Java class and click "OK".

If the "Java Class" option is still not showing up, you may need to check if your project SDK is properly configured in IntelliJ IDEA. You can do this by going to "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Project" and setting the correct "Project SDK" under the "Project SDK" dropdown.
If you are still facing issues, it might be helpful to check IntelliJ IDEA's official documentation or seek assistance from their support resources.

I have gone to file ->project structure->project->Sdk.

Here it is showing multiple option like no Sdk,17 Oracle openjdk 17.0.11,openjdk-22Oracle OpenJDK 22.0.1 which option to choose

You should choose the appropriate Java SDK version that you have installed on your system. In this case, you have several options to choose from, such as "Oracle OpenJDK 17.0.11" and "Oracle OpenJDK 22.0.1.

If you are not sure which version to choose, you can go with the latest version installed on your system for development. In this case, you may want to choose "Oracle OpenJDK 22.0.1" as it is a newer version.

Select the appropriate Java SDK version from the list and click on "OK" to save the changes. This should ensure that the project is configured to use the correct Java SDK, allowing you to create Java classes in IntelliJ IDEA. If you encounter any issues, try creating a new Java class after setting the SDK correctly.
